# Why is Wordpress showing PHP fatal error nested limits?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a PHP file that seems to operate fine on it's own, but when I try and load it on a Wordpress page using a shortcode, I'm getting a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '400' reached, aborting!` message. I know this is to do with xDebug (because I'm using Wamp locally), when this is disabled it is replaced with a `memory exhausted` message instead.

But as the file seems to work fine when executed by itself, why is Wordpress causing it to load differently?

```
function mk_house_oracle($atts = []) {
    
    ob_start();
    include ABSPATH.'newreadings/house_number_new.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
    
}
add_shortcode('mk-house-oracle', 'mk_house_oracle');
```

Contents of house_number_new.php:

```
<div id="house-number">
    
    <?php if(isset($_POST['number']) && is_numeric($_POST['number'])) {
        
        require('data/house_data.php');
        
        function get_vibration($number) {
            global $house_data;

            if (isset($house_data[$number])) return $number;

            $number = (string) $number;

            $vibration = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($number); $i++) $vibration += $number{$i};

            if (!isset($house_data[$vibration])) $vibration = get_vibration($vibration);

            return $vibration;
    }
        
        $vibration = get_vibration($_POST['number']);
            
        if(isset($house_data[$vibration])) { ?>
    
            <div id="reading">
                <div id="inReading">
                    <?php echo $house_data[$vibration]; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    <?php } else { ?>
    
            <p>You entered an invalid number.
            Please go back and try again.</p>
            
    <?php }
        
    } else { ?>
            
        <div id="start">
            <div id="inStart">
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="text" size="4" name="number" id="houseNumber" value="<?php echo (@$_POST['number']); ?>" required />
                    <button type="submit">Go</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
            
    <?php } ?>
    
</div>
```

Comment: If the `get_vibration` function doesn't find a match, it keeps recursing forever.

Comment: Is that not allowed in Wordpress then...? Is this the reason why it fails in Wordpress but not when run by itself?

Comment: Is what not allowed? Infinite recursion won't end well anywhere.

Comment: You probably found a match when you tried it on it's own. There's nothing wordpress-specific about the issue. The problem is as @GuyIncognito said, if it don't find a match, it calls itself over and over. It becomes an infinite loop.

Comment: I understand that, but as my question explains, whenever the code is run by itself (not with Wordpress), it works fine. Whenever I call the file and output the contentswhen used with a shortcode, I get the error.I'm trying to find out why running this through Wordpress is making the difference and causing the issue. The code itself works fine.

Comment: _"You probably found a match when you tried it on it's own"_ - Wasn't that a possible suggestion why that could happen?

Comment: It's too constistent for it to be that. The error message shows every time it's run via Wordpress.

Comment: It would fit your explanation here. Double check that it isn't the case. Try to find something that doesn't exist when running it on it's own.

Comment: I can't it always runs and returns the info from the data file.

Comment: The issue is within Wordpress as far as I can see.

Comment: _"and returns the info from the data file"_ - Yes, but you should try and find something that _don't exist_  in the data file. It can't really return something from it then, right? Either way, since you don't want to double check and test our suggestions, I'm out, or we risk wasting time trying to debug an issue that has already been solved.

Comment: It will always return something. But thanks for your comments. I'll leave it for a bit and will check back later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221510/discussion-between-lee-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: I owe all you guys an apology for not actually listening to what you were saying. After debugging the array from the required file, it turns out the data wasn't being included (and you were right).
This was actually easily fixed by placing a global $house_data declaration just before the call to require the file, and now works in Wordpress. So I'm going to delete this question, as it was my own stupidity. But thanks for the time you took to comment and try to help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The required file was being skipped (or to be more precise couldn't be accessed) so the array was empty. This is why the function kept recursing over itself.

Turns out by simple adding `global $house_data;` just before the call to require the file, brought it back into play, and this now works in Wordpress.

Oh, I also changed the require line to use `ABSPATH` to be sure it was looking in the correct place.

```
if(isset($_POST['number']) && is_numeric($_POST['number'])) {
        
    global $house_data;
    require(ABSPATH.'newreadings/data/house_data.php');
```